# GraphQL query Parameters from Azure Synapse Pipeline

Tags: graphql, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse-pipeline

I am trying to extract and populate data into Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL pool from an API using ADF pipelines. I was able to implement the query without any parameters using the Copy activity, but I have been encountering issues while trying to add parameters. Most of the methods used till now throws the "InValid JSON error".

Below is the sample query. How can I pass a parameter successfully?

```
query( $createdAt: DateTimeString ){
  Trans( last: 10, filter: { CreatedAt_gte: $createdAt } ) {
    pageInfo {
      hasPreviousPage
      hasNextPage
    }
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        invNumber
        subledgerId
        CreatedAt
        ModifiedAt
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your API details or sample  data?

Comment: Xledger API with Token based authentication - Used the POST method and request body to query the above sample code

Comment: could you please provide your sample data?

Comment: I have used the below query to filter the data. The LMDate varibale contains the last modified date from SQL.                                                                                                    {"query": "{ Transactions(last: 100, filter: {ownerDbId: 30556167}{headerModifiedAt_gte:@{variables('LMDate')}}) { edges { node {dbId  text             } } } }","variables":null,"operationName":null}

Comment: I was able to do it now with the following code "{"query": "{ Transactions(last: 10000, filter: {ownerDbId: 1000,headerModifiedAt_gte: \"@{variables('LMDate')}\"}) }   , but it fails when I pass timestamp along with the date value.

Comment: What kind of payload you want to pass? What does date value along with timestamp mean? Can you provide sample data